# Azure CLI inside IDE for publishing Azure Functions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-cli

I installed Azure CLI from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-powershell). I want to publish my function to Azure by running `func azure functionapp publish MyAppName` in my PyCharm terminal.

What I get is `` Unable to connect to Azure. Make sure you have the `az` CLI or `Az.Accounts` PowerShell module installed and logged in and try again ``. So the CLI was installed only on my System's PowerShell and CommandPrompt and I can run `az` commands and execute `func azure functionapp publish MyAppName` only there.

How do I make this work on PyCharm terminal as well.

Comment: Have you logged using "az login" ?

Comment: @CSharpRocks az command works only in my cmd, not in PyCharm terminal

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command on PyCharm Terminal which will install all the Azure CLI Modules:

```
pip install azure-cli
```

[image]

Next Login to your Azure account using the command `az login` in the same PyCharm Terminal, it will take you to browser to login with your account:

[image]

Below is the Azure CLI Command for publishing the Azure Function App:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n \
<app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

Refer to this Official doc of [Azure CLI Function Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest) on more information.